# Setting (click) Attribute on Anchor Element

Tags: angular, renderer, elementref

As I understand it it is not possible to dynamically add a '(click)' attribute to an element of the DOM using Renderer2 in Angular 2+.

If this is true how do you lovely people add a '(click)' attribute when they are dynamically creating HTML in the component or what workaround do you use?

```
 const element = this.renderer.createElement('a');

 element.setAttribute('href', 'foobar');     // This works
 element.setAttribute('(click)', 'foobar');  // This does not work
```

Comment: Why don't you use `this.renderer.setAttribute`? You can use `this.renderer.listen` for this.

Comment: If you use `element.setAttribute` then it should be `onclick`, not `(click)`. And the proper way is using `renderer.setAttribute` as mentioned by @Lends

Comment: `(click)` isn't a valid attribute name anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(click)** is not an attribute and you can't use it like this. 
you may use `.addEventListener` 
**for example** 
    element.addEventListener('click', function(){ do something} );

if you want full angular example : 
**HTML**

```
<button #mybtn>my Button</button>
```

**TS**

```
 @ViewChild('mybtn') myBtn:ElementRef;
    ngOnInit() {
      this.myBtn.nativeElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
       console.log('from there');
      })
    }
```

Comment: Many thanks for that @Yahya Essam, it got me on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Renderer2` to add attributes and event listeners. I think it is better to use the `Renderer2` since it acts like a wrapper and abstracts how the DOM manipulation works under the hood.

```
 const element = this.renderer.createElement('a');
 this.renderer.setAttribute(element, 'href', 'foobar');
 this.renderer.listen(element, 'click', this.myMethod);
```

[Here is a working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-renderer2-clicklistener)